# Запустить python скрипт из php и получить результат обратно в php

Tags: php, python

Всем привет.
Интересует такой вопрос.
Каким образом можно из php скрипта запустить python скрипт, обработать в нем некоторые данные, и получить результат работы скрипта и данные обратно в php ?

Comment: также интересует, как передать параметры, например массив чисел в скрипт

Comment: Надо ещё добавить к ответам, что exec-функции в PHP часто заблокированы на уровне php.ini по соображениям безопасности.

Answer (score 5):

В зависимости от того, что вы делаете, system () или popen ().

Используйте system (), если код Python не имеет выхода, или если вы хотите, чтобы выход скрипта Python переходил непосредственно в браузер.

Используйте popen (), если вы хотите записать данные на стандартный ввод скрипта Python или прочитать данные из стандартного вывода сценария Python в php. Popen () позволит вам читать или писать, но не то, и другое. Если вы хотите оба, проверьте proc_open (), но с двухсторонней связью между программами вы должны быть осторожны, чтобы избежать взаимоблокировок, где каждая программа ждет другого, чтобы что-то сделать.

Если вы хотите передать данные, предоставленные пользователем, в сценарий Python, то самое важное, о чем нужно заботиться, - это командная инъекция. Если вы не будете осторожны, ваш пользователь может отправить вам такие данные, как «; evilcommand»; И заставить вашу программу выполнять произвольный код.

Escapeshellarg () и escapeshellcmd () могут помочь с этим, но лично мне нравится удалять все, что не является известными хорошими данными, используя что-то вроде

Preg_replace ('/ [^ a-zA-Z0-9] /', '', $ str)

[Источник:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166944/calling-python-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = system('python myscript.py myargs', $retval);
```

[function.system.php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.system.php)

```
$python =  shell_exec('C:\Python27\python.exe e:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\test.py');
```

[function.shell-exec.php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php) (функция недоступна в безопасном режиме)

Comment: как передать параметры в скрипт, например массив?